# Keep getting error on get request in production (MongoDB mlab, React/Redux, Webpack, heroku)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, react-redux, redux-saga

This problem has been driving me crazy which pushed me to make an account here hoping someone can help. My app has been deployed for about 5-6 months and was working fine until I checked it about a week ago. The app (both local and AWS deployed) works if I have the server running with babel-node server.js in terminal. This is because it keeps trying to use localhost to get the games when it is supposed to use mongodb through heroku. I tried clearing the heroku cache, editing various parts of the code to no avail and I am stuck. I've only been coding for 2 years so I am sure someone here with more experience could figure this out, at least I am hoping. It is an older project with older dependencies but it should still be working. The front-end is hosted on AWS and the backend through Heroku. I'm also using the Filestack API but I don't believe the error is from there.

I think the error is in games.js in the sagas folder or maybe GamesListManager.jsx in the components folder. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

P.S. If you are looking at the github repo and my commits, make sure to go back to the last Jan 11 commit as that was the last working version (and the version deployed to AWS).

http://www.oldschoolgames.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/
https://github.com/shahramg92/Videogame-library-react/tree/2327f503e204381745eacc996a2ccbdb09fac970

snippet of possible problem (in src/sagas/games.js)

const API_URL = process.env.API_URL || 'http://localhost:8081';

I think it keeps trying to access local host (when I inspect it keeps saying failed get request from local host).

Comment: Please add the relevant snippets from your code to your question instead of linking to github.

Comment: I posted a small snippet but I don't think it will make sense unless someone goes through a bit of the code as I am not sure exactly where the error is.